# RxJs skip sampleTime on startWith value

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I want to skip the sampleTime on the startWith value.
The Observable should emit false instantly and only then use sampleTime.

I want the Observable to emit booleans. On click of a loading button a Loadingspinner should be displayed until the data is delivered, but at least for one second. The data$ Observable instantly emits null and then eventually the requested data.

```
showLoadingSpinner$ = this.data$.pipe(
  map(x => x == null),
  sampleTime(1000),
  startWith(false),
)
```

How can I do this? Should i use a different operator?

Comment: In your case `startWith` after `sampleTime`, startWith value will emit immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So you can use [concat](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat), where the observable will be executed sequentially, first we create an observable that takes only the first value without sampleTime, then after that completes due to `take` we will go to the second observable where we have `sampleTime`

```js
const data$ = rxjs.interval(1000);
let first = true;
showLoadingSpinner$ = rxjs.concat(
  data$.pipe(rxjs.take(1)), // first
  data$.pipe(rxjs.sampleTime(2000)) // second
).pipe(
  rxjs.map(x => x == null),
  rxjs.startWith(false),
).subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.6.0/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha512-  ejsljG9xAKvLl8gCL5FQmGLQ5dZvr2g9n7iwBYG3bIAmfPwjA4P2tX6lvvj2ry+cUpmiuBaF70F3Y5/6o/KrPQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```